# A question about submanifolds

Tags: manifolds

I need help with the following problem:

> Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold. Let $f\colon M\to M$ be a smooth mapping satisfying  $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for each $x \in M$. Show that $f(M)$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$.

I'd like to prove that $\operatorname{rank}(df_x)$ is locally constant. If so, $\operatorname{rank}(d_xf)$ would be a constant and then I could solve this problem. But I failed after several tries. Beside, I noticed that $df_x$ is a projection for each $x$ of $f(M)$, and I doubt this conclusion is useful though I'm still confused.

Thanks for your help and advice!

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? This is a challenging problem, but you need to make some effort and work on it, not just expect us to write you a textbook.

Comment: Thanks. It's not my homework but I've been stuck in it for days. I'd like to prove that the rank(df_x) is locally constant, but failed. Beside, I notice that df_x is a projection for each x of f(M), but Idon't know how to use this conclusion.

Comment: Interesting!  Not to be a doubter, but what makes you think this is true?

Comment: This is an exercise in a book.

Comment: OK, it *must* be true! ;)  But seriously folks, I've had a chance to mull it over and and I can see it at this point ; e.g. let $M = M_1 \times M_2$ and take $f(x,y) = (x_0, y)$ for some $x_0 \in M_1$ etc.